# Unpack XAP file

Tags: windows-phone-8

Just stupid question: how to unpack XAP file for WP8.
I read a lot of posts like "its just a zip" but it wont work: zip signature is PK, but xap have PRE signature and wont be opened by any zip programs.
I got xap from windows phone marketplace.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to .zip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XAP really are ZIP file. If you build an application with Visual Studio, you'll be able to open the generated XAP file with most ZIP uncompressors.

The issue you're facing is that you've downloaded the XAP from the marketplace. Those are encrypted (to prevent piracy) and can only be decrypted by a Windows Phone device.

Comment: To be slightly more specific, all marketplace XAPs are signed with Microsofts DRM technology. (And yes, the OP is asking about reverse-engineering something he downloaded)

Answer (score 1):

hmm, I suspect the main piece of decrypting an encrypted XAP is not a WP device but an internet connection to WP marketplace and an acount with that XAP application registered as payed so you can get that way the key for decrypting that particular xap. ...so no, you cant unpack an xap from marketplace

Comment: I dont think it has to do with your account. You can download any app's encrypted XAP manually from windowsphone.com, without being logged in. Then you load them to a device from an SD card. Decryption must happen on the device end.

Comment: If we ever get root access to Windows Phone then may be able to decompile the encrypted apps.